# verification while loop in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have a question about a while loop. I have been searching and I can't find anything that will assist. I might be missing something. I am a little new with shell. I am trying to verify the user password to make sure that it is correct. I was able to get part of it but the loop exits out once the user inputs their password. I want to loop to continue until it is complete. Below I have attached what I do have. I know that I am missing something, I am just not sure. I was able to create an infinite loop but I wasn't able to figure the rest out.

```
read -p "Input new username please?: " user
read -p "Input password: " password
read -p "Re-enter password: " verify
if [ "$password" != "$verify" ]
then
echo "Password does not match. Please try again."
else
echo "Password Successful!!"
fi
```

Comment: There's no loop in that code...

Comment: Use `while : ; do` put your code here. If the password matches include `break` and at the end of the loop put a `done`

Answer (score 1):

If you are still stuck, continuing from the comment, what you want to do is simply wrap your code in a continual loop and provide a `break` statement when the passwords match. A convenient form of a continual loop is:

```sh
  while :
  do
    ## your code goes here
  done
```

The `':'` operator tests `true` each iteration.

You can rearrange your `if` statement as `if [ "$password" = "$verify" ]` and then output success and `break` to terminate (e.g. jump out of the loop) at that point. There is no need for the `else` part. If the passwords don't match, just output the error message and loop again.

Another improvement would be to use `printf` instead of `echo` (in all cases). The `printf` function is far superior and provides the same output format control as [man 3 printf for C](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

while :     ## loop continually
do
    read -p "Input username    : " user
    read -p "Input password    : " password
    read -p "Re-enter password : " verify
    
    if [ "$password" = "$verify" ]      ## check for match
    then
        printf "\nPassword Successful!!\n"
        break;
    fi
    
    ## otherwise loop again
    printf "\nerror: Password does not match. Please try again.\n\n" >&2
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sh pwchk.sh
Input username    : myUser
Input password    : myGoodPass
Re-enter password : myBadPass

error: Password does not match. Please try again.

Input username    : myUser
Input password    : myGoodPass
Re-enter password : myGoodPass

Password Successful!!
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks. That did work and I see how that is better than what I was doing. As I am new to shell and still working through a command line book that I purchased, I do have a question you said that printf is superior and does the same thing. Is that something that I should use as good practice? I want to make sure that I have good coding habits

Comment: Thank you very much. I also appreciate the information this is going to help me as I move forward with scripting.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a loop, but you can add one with something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

read -p "Input new username please?: " user
while
        read -p "Input password: " password
        read -p "Re-enter password: " verify
        test "$password" != "$verify"
do
        echo "Password does not match. Please try again." >&2
done
```

That gets a little sloppy about handling EOF, so you might want to check the reads with:

```
#!/bin/sh

read -p "Input new username please?: " user || exit
while
        read -p "Input password: " password \
        && read -p "Re-enter password: " verify \
        && test "$password" != "$verify"
do
        echo "Password does not match. Please try again." >&2
done
```

You might want to suppress the printing of the password as it is being typed, which you can do with:

```
#!/bin/sh

trap 'stty echo' EXIT
read -p "Input new username please?: " user || exit
while
        stty -echo echonl
        read -p "Input password: " password \
        && read -p "Re-enter password: " verify \
        && test "$password" != "$verify"
do
        echo "Password does not match. Please try again." >&2
done
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. That is something that I wasn't sure how to hide the users input when the password is inputted. I see a few different things like, "trap" I have to look that up because I never seen that before and I need to figure that out and see how I can use it.

Comment: The `trap` is a mechanism for doing cleanup.  After `stty -echo`, if you don't invoke `stty echo` you won't see what you type even after the script ends.  You can call `stty echo` manually, but you need to ensure that you catch all code paths.  By putting it in a trap, it will be invoked no matter how the script terminates (unless the script is terminated by a KILL signal).  Since you probably have more code after the password prompt, it would make sense to call it directly after the while loop.

Comment: Okay, that is good to know. Learn something new everyday.